# Font Awesome Library not working with Angular Material library in Angular Project

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome, angular-material-theming

I was trying to use font awesome css in my project but the css doesn't get applied to HTML elements.
If i **remove** Angular Material theme then only the Font Awesome CSS is working. But then Angular Material Components will not work!!!

```
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Any guidance for this - 
[image]

Comment: did you try to change the order of imports

Comment: no it didn't work out

Answer (score 1):

In angular.json, we have styles property which will allow to load third party css files.

```
"styles": [
     "node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
     "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
],
```

Comment: yes it's the same as you put these in styles.css - the thing might be both material css and font-awesome aren't working together!!!

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways is to import the CSS at the global level in the index.html in src folder. 
You can do this with a simple `<link rel=“stylesheet” href=“/fontawesome.css`

That should hopefully fix issue

Comment: Can you give an example of the html element with the FontAwesome class in it? Possibly making a little Stackblitz may be helpful to understand